# What does "Initialize" mean? I have just connected my micro-SD card to my Mac, this just shows up

Tags: mac, sd-card

The micro-sd card is used as the storage of my dashcam. It works fine before. But today when I connected it to my Mac, as usual, there is a popup saying:

[image]

It seems my sd-card has broken. But what does "Initialize..." meaning? If I click it, what would happen?

Will I lose all my data?

Thanks,

Comment: You will still get one more popup, indicated by the three dots after the word initialise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Initialize' means 'Format'

The ellipsis …  following it is standard 'computer speak' for "this won't happen before you see some more options."

So, for whatever reason, your computer cannot read the existing format on the card & wants to attempt to erase & start afresh. That would lose all data already on the card.

Re-test it in your dashcam, but be prepared to bin it & buy a new one. They're really fragile structures & easily fail. You could try data recovery software if the data is valuable.

It would also be worth removing & reinserting the card & rebooting the Mac, just in case it was a one-off glitch, dirty contacts, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If your Mac can't read an SD card it proposes to reformat/initialize it so it can be used. This will put new data structures onto the SD card, reducing your chance of recovering any data from it.

[Disk Drill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/memory-card-recovery-mac.html) claims to be able to recover data from damaged SD cards. I don't have any experience with it but it might be worth a try.